# Using "does" + verb in an affirmative sentence

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, third-person-singular

Is it good to write "does" and then verb in an affirmative sentence? Also, should then, the verb ends with 's'?

Like:

> "She does play(-s?) guitar".

Should I put -s? Is it common in a regular speech? I have a doubt, that this construction uses, when someone wants to approve something straightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if we use **does** the verb **does** has the third-person form and thus the verb **play** should have the bare form:

> She does play the guitar.

If you merely want to say that the girl plays the guitar, it's more common to say:

> She plays the guitar.

The form with **does** has more emphasis:

> -- "I don't think she knows how to play the guitar."
>   -- "She **does play** the guitar!"

Reference: [English auxiliary verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auxiliaries_and_contractions) (Wikipedia).

Comment: As well, if I there is "should"? (no s ending)

Comment: @Artur - "She should **play** the guitar" (also the base form - because a verb coming after an auxiliary verb (like **should**) does not take the -s ending.

Comment: So, better to say "she does play the guitar" or "she plays the guitar" in a common speech?

Comment: @Artur - if you merely relate the information, it's "She plays the guitar". If you want to emphasise that she indeed plays it, if you want to put more stress on it, then "She does play the guitar!" (I'm sure of it!)